# Push data into power bi using java azure ad library

Tags: java, azure, powerbi, adal, azure-active-directory

I am knew to java, azure ad and power bi and I want to test pushing data into power bi using the azure ad java library (ADAL) here : http://innerdot.com/azure/authenticating-to-azure-resource-manager-using-java

I've created a netbeans project and used this code : http://innerdot.com/azure/authenticating-to-azure-resource-manager-using-java and tested it so that I know I have all rights to access my azure ad application.

In the Power BI documentation, we tell you to register your app and get the authentication token which will help you use the API to send GET/POST.. requests

I used a sample code I found on Github. However, following the examples in the power bi apiary docs I get a "403" or "404" http reponse status.

```
 public class ApplicationAuthExample {

    private final static String AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
    private final static String ARM_ENDPOINT = "https://management.azure.com/";
    private static final boolean DEV_MODE = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String username = null;
        String credential = null;
        String tenantId = null;
        String clientId = null;
        String subscriptionId = null;

        if (DEV_MODE) {
            username = "name.name@entity.com";
            credential = "******";
            clientId = "50xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            tenantId = "bbexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            subscriptionId = "16bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        } else {
            if ((!args[0].equals("service-principal") && !args[0].equals("user"))
                    || (args[0].equals("user") && args.length != 6)
                    || (args[0].equals("service-principal") && args.length != 5)) {
                System.out.println("Usage:");
                System.out.println(" user <username> <password> <client id> <tenant id> <subscription id>");
                System.out.println(" service-principal <password> <client id> <tenant id> <subscription id>");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            int idx = 1;
            if (args[0].equals("user")) {
                username = args[idx++];
            }
            credential = args[idx++];
            clientId = args[idx++];
            tenantId = args[idx++];
            subscriptionId = args[idx++];
        }

        // use adal to Authenticate
        AuthenticationContext context = null;
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        ExecutorService service = null;

        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            String url = AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT + tenantId + "/oauth2/authorize";
            context = new AuthenticationContext(url,
                    false,
                    service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = null;
            if (username == null) {
                System.out.println("username = null");
                ClientCredential cred = new ClientCredential(clientId, credential);
                future = context.acquireToken(ARM_ENDPOINT, cred, null);
            } else {
                future = context.acquireToken(ARM_ENDPOINT, clientId,
                        username, credential, null);
            }
            result = future.get();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred:");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }

        // make a request to list available providers
        String url = ARM_ENDPOINT
                + "subscriptions/" + subscriptionId
                + "/providers"
                + "?api-version=2014-04-01-preview";
//        String url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets";
        String body = null;
        try {
            //final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            //HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 10000);
             RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(5000)
                .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
                .build();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.setConfig(requestConfig);
            System.out.println("url : "+url);
            httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.getAccessToken());
           // httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.getAccessToken());
//            System.out.println("token : "+result.getAccessToken());
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            System.out.println("status : "+statusCode);
            if(statusCode == 403){
                System.out.println(statusCode+": acces denied");
            }
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream), 1000);
            for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            instream.close();
            body = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("body : "+body);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I known, the endpoints in your code are only for service on Azure, not for PowerBI. Please follow the PowerBI offical [document](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-walkthrough-push-data-get-token/) to set the endpoints for authenticating, and see the document [`Push data into a Power BI Dashboard`](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-walkthrough-push-data/) to know how to get started.

For [authenticating to PowerBI service](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-to-power-bi-service/), please according to your needs to register a client app or a web app that needs different authentication.

There is a [sample](https://github.com/satalyst/powerbi-rest-java) which I searched in GitHub, that includes the code for getting access token for PowerBI authentication using Java, please see https://github.com/satalyst/powerbi-rest-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/satalyst/powerbi/impl/Office365Authenticator.java.

Hope it helps.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded the maven project and opened it in netbeans. I created a java App to test it as it is shown here: http://satalyst.com/open-source-powerbi-rest-api-for-java/ But I get an error : To sign into this application the account must be added to the analysis.windows.net directory

Answer (score 0):

After testing it in C# and going back to java, I finally managed to establish the connexion and get a valid token:

```
public class ApplicationAuth {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String username = null;
    String credential = null;
    String clientId = null;

    username = "xxxx.xxxxx@company.com";
    credential = "************";
    clientId = "50xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

    // use adal to Authenticate
    AuthenticationContext context = null;
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    ExecutorService service = null;

    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);           
        String url = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";
        context = new AuthenticationContext(url,
                false,
                service);
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = null;
        if (username==null) {
            System.out.println("username = null");
            ClientCredential cred = new ClientCredential(clientId, credential);
            future = context.acquireToken("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api", cred, null);
        } else {
            future = context.acquireToken("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api", clientId,
                    username, credential, null);

        }
        result = future.get();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred:");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    String body = null;
    String token = result.getAccessToken();
    try {

        DatasetsHandler datasetH = new DatasetsHandler();
        String data = "{\"name\": \"JavaDatasetTest\", \"tables\": " +
         "[{\"name\": \"Product\", \"columns\": " +
         "[{ \"name\": \"ProductID\", \"dataType\": \"Int64\"}, " +
         "{ \"name\": \"Name\", \"dataType\": \"string\"}, " +
         "{ \"name\": \"Category\", \"dataType\": \"string\"}," +
         "{ \"name\": \"IsCompete\", \"dataType\": \"bool\"}," +
         "{ \"name\": \"ManufacturedOn\", \"dataType\": \"DateTime\"}" +
         "]}]}";

        //datasetH.CreateDataset(data, token);   
        System.out.println("after creating dataset");
        body = datasetH.GetDatasets(token);
        String datasetID = datasetH.GetDatasetID(token);
        System.out.println("dataset ID: "+datasetID);    

        String rows = "{\"rows\":" +
        "[{\"ProductID\":1,\"Name\":\"Adjustable Race\",\"Category\":\"Components\",\"IsCompete\":true,\"ManufacturedOn\":\"07/30/2014\"}," +
        "{\"ProductID\":2,\"Name\":\"LL Crankarm\",\"Category\":\"Components\",\"IsCompete\":true,\"ManufacturedOn\":\"07/30/2014\"}," +
        "{\"ProductID\":3,\"Name\":\"HL Mountain Frame - Silver\",\"Category\":\"Bikes\",\"IsCompete\":true,\"ManufacturedOn\":\"07/30/2014\"}]}";

        String resu = datasetH.AddRows( datasetID, token, "Product", rows);

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }
   // System.out.println("body : "+body); //{"value":[]}
  }  

}
```

Here are the methods I use:

```
public class DatasetsHandler {

public String powerBIDatasetsApiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets";

public String GetDatasets(String token) throws IOException{

    HttpRequests httpRequest = new HttpRequests();       
    HttpResponse response = httpRequest.HttpHeaderParams(token, powerBIDatasetsApiUrl, "GET", "");

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream), 1000);
    for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    instream.close();
    String body = sb.toString();

    return body;
}

public void CreateDataset(String data, String token) throws IOException{           

    HttpRequests httpRequest = new HttpRequests(); 
    HttpResponse response = httpRequest.HttpHeaderParams(token, powerBIDatasetsApiUrl, "POST", data);

    System.out.println("createDataset response: "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println("entity: "+entity);
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream), 1000);
    for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    instream.close();
    String body = sb.toString();

    System.out.println("created dataset");

}

public String GetDatasetID(String token) throws IOException{

    int id_count = 0;
    DatasetsHandler DatasetH = new DatasetsHandler();
    String result  = DatasetH.GetDatasets(token);

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray geodata = jObject.getJSONArray("value");

    for (int i = 0; i<geodata.length(); i++){
        try{
            JSONObject cdataset = geodata.getJSONObject(i);
            id_count = id_count +1;
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            // If id doesn't exist, this exception is thrown
        }
    }

    JSONObject cdataset = geodata.getJSONObject(id_count -1);
    String Id = cdataset.getString("id");
    System.out.println("get dataset name : "+cdataset.getString("name"));
    System.out.println("get dataset id : "+cdataset.getString("id"));
    return Id;
}

public String AddRows(String DatasetID, String token, String TableName, String rows) throws IOException{

    String url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/"+DatasetID+"/tables/"+TableName+"/rows";
    HttpRequests httpRequest = new HttpRequests(); 
    HttpResponse response = httpRequest.HttpHeaderParams(token, url, "POST", rows);

    System.out.println("Rows Added");
    return response.getEntity().toString();
}
```

}

And the HttpHandelr:

```
public class HttpRequests {

public HttpRequestBase httpRequest;
public static Gson gson = new Gson();
public HttpResponse HttpHeaderParams (String token, String powerBIApiUrl, String method, String body) throws IOException {      

    final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(body);
    StringEntity  dataset = new StringEntity(body);

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setSocketTimeout(5000)
            .setConnectTimeout(5000)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
            .build();

    if("GET".equals(method)){
        httpRequest = new HttpGet(powerBIApiUrl);
    }else if("POST".equals(method)){
        System.out.println("===POST METHOD");
        httpRequest = new HttpPost(powerBIApiUrl);
        ((HttpPost)httpRequest).setEntity(dataset);
        System.out.println("get entity: "+((HttpPost)httpRequest).getEntity());
    }
    System.out.println("TOKEN: "+token);
    httpRequest.setConfig(requestConfig);
    httpRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    httpRequest.setHeader("ContentLength", "\""+body.length()+"\"");

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
    System.out.println("response: "+Arrays.toString(response.getAllHeaders()));
    System.out.println("response: "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    return response;
   } 
}
```

I hope It helps :)